# How to pass a string from C# to a javascript variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, string, variables

i like to pass a string from C# to a javascript variable.
The simple way is like:

```
string aaa = "hello";
```

and then

```
<script>
    var javacriptVariable = "<%=aaa%>";
</script>
```

But, I am asking if there is another way without using a `<script>` block to to make that variable into a javascript equivalent, direclty using ONLY C# code.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use RegisterClientScriptBlock to write the javascript that sets the variable. Or use json to pull the variable.

Comment: How do you expect to use the javascript var if it's not inside a script block?

Comment: `RegisterStartupScript` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx

Comment: You could have a [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) in your ASP.NET page and you can set it with C# and access it with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Write it to a div's `InnerHtml` in C#, and get the div's `innerHTML` from your JavaScript code.

**Notes:**

1. You'll have to make the div `runat="server"`.
2. Notice the difference in the casing (uppercase/lowercase) between
   the C#'s `InnerHtml`  and js's `innerHTML` .

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best method would be to include `JSON.NET` and output it:

```
var aaa = <%= JsonConvert.Serialize(aaa) %>;
```

Then, no matter if it's a string, integer, array, or whatever it'll be serialized in a way that JS can handle it. this will also handle any kind of escaping if necessary (e.g. `aaa = "Hello \"World\"!"`)

Another option is to retrieve it with a handler/AJAX (but that's a little too much overhead for such a simple task).

Finally, you can register the script:

```
Type type = this.GetType();
string scriptName = "assign aaa";
ClientScriptManager clientScript = Page.ClientScript;
if (!clientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(type, scripName))
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">")
      .AppendFormat("var aaa = {0};", JsonConvert.Serialize(aaa))
      .Append("</" + "script>");
    clientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, scripName, sb.ToString());
}
```

But the above is just a more elaborate way of ending up with a `<script>` tag anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a nuget pacakge called [Ngon](https://github.com/brooklynDev/NGon) that does exactly this:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/NGon/

It's a rip of the rails gem [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)